# Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, e^{2 \pi i/3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2} + e^{2 \pi i/3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I have seen this same question answered here, but I would like to know if I could arrive to the solution with any of my approaches. [Splitting field of x^3-2 as a simple extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665353/splitting-field-of-x3-2-as-a-simple-extension)

Clearly $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2} + e^{2 \pi i/3}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, e^{2 \pi i/3})$, so the only thing left to do is prove it the other way.

**1st attemp**

To see that $\sqrt[3]{2}, e^{2 \pi i/3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2} + e^{2 \pi i/3})$ would be enough. For this, I have seen that a common approach is to compute $(\sqrt[3]{2} + e^{2 \pi i/3})^{-1}$ and generaly you obtain an element that summed with $\sqrt[3]{2} + e^{2 \pi i/3}$ results in $\sqrt[3]{2}$ or $e^{2 \pi i/3}$. I am having a really hard time trying to rationalize it.

**2nd attemp**

I try to reason it by using the degrees of the extension. We have that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, e^{2 \pi i/3}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2} + e^{2 \pi i/3})] = \frac{[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, e^{2 \pi i/3}) : \mathbb{Q}]}{[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2} + e^{2 \pi i/3}) : \mathbb{Q}]}$.

I think the esiest way to get $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, e^{2 \pi i/3}) : \mathbb{Q}]$ is by presenting a $\mathbb{Q}$-base. Although I think I am not doing it right, because seeing this question [Splitting field of x^3-2 as a simple extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665353/splitting-field-of-x3-2-as-a-simple-extension), I think it should be of degree 6, not 7.

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, e^{2 \pi i/3}) = \mathbb{Q}\langle1, \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{4}, \sqrt[3]{2}e^{2 \pi i/3}, \sqrt[3]{2}e^{4 \pi i/3}, \sqrt[3]{4}e^{2 \pi i/3}, \sqrt[3]{4}e^{4 \pi i/3}\rangle$

To compute $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2} + e^{2 \pi i/3}) : \mathbb{Q}]$ we can try to find the irreducible polynomial.

$$
\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2} + e^{2 \pi i/3} \\
\alpha^3 = (\sqrt[3]{2} + e^{2 \pi i/3})^3 \\
\alpha^3 = 2 + 3\sqrt[3]{4}e^{2 \pi i/3} + 3\sqrt[3]{2}e^{4 \pi i/3} + 1 \\
\frac{1}{3}(\alpha^3 - 3) = \sqrt[3]{4}e^{2 \pi i/3} + \sqrt[3]{2}e^{4 \pi i/3} \\
\frac{1}{3}(\alpha^3 - 3) = \sqrt[3]{2}e^{2 \pi i/3}(\sqrt[3]{2} + e^{2 \pi i/3}) \\
\frac{1}{3}(\alpha^3 - 3) = \sqrt[3]{2}e^{2 \pi i/3}\alpha \\
\frac{1}{27}(\alpha^3 - 3)^3 = 2\alpha^3 \\
\frac{1}{27}(\alpha^9 - 9\alpha^6 + 27\alpha^3-27) = 2\alpha^3 \\
\alpha^9 - 9\alpha^6 - 27\alpha^3-27 = 0 
$$

So clearly, $\sqrt[3]{2} + e^{2 \pi i/3}$ is a root of the polynomial $p(x) = x^9 - 9x^6 - 27x^3-27$. But it does not seem irreducible.

I am stuck at this point. Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: +1 for showing your work. Sorry about not commenting sooner, I was looking for [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1804448/11619), because mimicking that approach may be more to your liking. You do know how to write $e^{2\pi i/3}$ using $\sqrt{-3}$.

Comment: Your basis is a bit off. I think the most natural basis for this extension is gotten as pairwise product of the two bases $\{1,\root3\of2,\root3\of4\}$ and $\{1,e^{2\pi i/3}\}$. So
$$\{1,\root3\of2,\root3\of4,e^{2\pi i/3}, e^{2\pi i/3}\root3\of2,e^{2\pi i/3}\root3\of4\}.$$

Comment: Mind you, the recommend way of typesetting a generated algebraic structure is to use `\langle` and `\rangle` to get the Left and Right angles around a set of generators. They look prettier than `<` and `>`. Also, the comparison signs leave (by design) a bit more space around them, which is something many don't want to see when describing a generated structure.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh, the clue of $\sqrt(-3)$ is very good! I guess that you are using that it is a root of $x^2 + x + 1$, so $e^{2\pi i/3} = (-1 \pm \sqrt{-3})/2$, therfore if you have $\sqrt{-3}$ you are done, I will try with this approach again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
x^9-9x^6-27x^3-27=(x^6 + 3x^5 + 6x^4 + 3x^3 + 9x + 9)(x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 3).
$$
The factors are irreducible, so we have the desired result for degree $6$, which you have linked: [Splitting field of x^3-2 as a simple extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665353/splitting-field-of-x3-2-as-a-simple-extension)

Comment: The problem is that I do not see how can you arrive at that conclusion if you have not seen the result before. As I understand factoring polynomials is a very difficult task.

Comment: And then I am getting that the degree of the other extension is 7, I guess because I am not seeing that one of the elements of the base I have written is linearly dependent.

Comment: No, factoring is not so difficult here, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials). The degree of the minimal polynomial is $6$. By definition, this is the field degree then.